# What word means a “collection of diaries”?

Tags: single-word-requests, collective-nouns

I like to collect diaries but I couldn’t find any word for this hobby nor for what a collection of diaries is called.  If anyone knows please share.

Answer (score 2):

When I think I of a collection of diaries some words that come to mind are:

1. archive
2. catalogue

Comment: archive is kind of document collection and I have diaries in which few are blank so is it really suitable?

Comment: You collect blank diaries?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a word like Numismatic ( of coins ) there isn't one, however that doesn't mean we can't invent one:

Using the same etemological rules as Numismatic and Numismatist, let's construct a new word.

We shall say Ephemerismatic (of diaries) and Ephemerismatist.

So you are an *ephemerismatist* and you are interested in *ephemrismatics*.

Comment: I am wondering why you are capitalizing Certain Words here.

Comment: I was really not expecting neologism but thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that *archive* is the term officially used also for diaries:

[National Diary Archive](http://nationaldiaryarchive.com/category/diaries-2/collecting-diaries/)

> Interview With Sally Macnamara, Collector of Handwritten Diaries
>   Not long ago I started corresponding with Sally Macnamara Ivey who has collected and sold diaries since about 1987.